# How to solve alignment issue on CSS Grid Critters 9.3

Tags: css, css-grid, grid-layout

Need help solving [CSS Grid Critters 9.3](https://mastery.games/courses/gridcritters/lectures/5219286)

I can get the grid template lines to fit correctly, but the bottom row of items won't line up.

[image: CSS Grid Critters 9.3 Problem]

Here's what I've got:

```
planet {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 50% auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  justify-items: end;
  align-content: space-between;
}
```

But bottom row doesn't seem to fit. Tried applying styling to

```
dunes {}
```

and

```
water {}
```

But that just messed up the top row. Struggling going back and forth between lessons to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, after reviewing previous lessons, it struck me. I needed to test out the align-items property.

[This solution worked!](https://twitter.com/DaniAmsalem/status/1211548052772671489)

```
planet {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 50% auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  justify-items: end;
  align-content: space-between; /***this is the key***/
}
```

It turns out, that [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) and [align-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content) work together to control the space around content items aka "boxes" or "tracks". By default, `justify-content` handles left/right space whereas `align-content` handles top/bottom space.

On the other hand, [justify-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items) and [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) control the actual position of the items inside the boxes or tracks. It's worth mentioning that `align-items` throws off the position of the top row, so don't use it. `Justify-items` fixes the top row without throwing off the bottom row.

[image: Grid Critters 9.3 Solved]